# What's the suffix (type character) for "Byte" numeric constants in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, types, constants

Just out of curiosity:

I know I can tell the compiler if I want a value to be interpreted as a certain numeric type, e.g. as Integer (32 bit signed), this way appending an "I" (type character) to the constant value:

```
Private Function GetTheAnswerAsInteger() As Integer

   Return 42I

End Function
```

There's also "S" for Short, "D" for Decimal, etc.

But what is the **suffix for Byte**? Hint: it's not the obvious one "B"...

Answer (score 31, accepted):

There isn't one. If you need to distinguish between an integer and a byte (e.g. to call an appropriate overload) for a constant, you need to cast.

(The same is true in C#, by the way.)

[MSDN provides confirmation:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e2ayt412.aspx)

> Byte has no literal type character or
>   identifier type character.

There's also a [list of type characters and literal suffixes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s9cz43ek.aspx).

Comment: Little poor Byte, doesn't even have a literal type character... ;-)

Comment: For C# folks this section of the specification shows the various options. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664674%28VS.71%29.aspx

Comment: @JonSkeet - Noting the other replies here about the addition to Roslyn of `SB` & `UB` in 2015, why can I still not use these in my VB (VS 2017)? Do I need to adjust some setting?

Answer (score 6):

> So, we added binary literals in VB last fall and got similar feedback
>   from early testers. We did decide to add a suffix for byte for VB. We
>   settled on SB (for signed byte) and UB (for unsigned byte). The reason
>   it's not just B and SB is two-fold.
>
> One, the B suffix is ambiguous if you're writing in hexadecimal (what
>   does 0xFFB mean?) and even if we had a solution for that, or another
>   character than 'B' ('Y' was considered, F# uses this) no one could
>   remember whether the default was signed or unsigned - .NET bytes are
>   unsigned by default so it would make sense to pick B and SB but all
>   the other suffixes are signed by default so it would be consistent
>   with other type suffixes to pick B and UB. In the end we went for
>   unambiguous SB and UB.
>   -- Anthony D. Green,

https://roslyn.codeplex.com/discussions/542111

It has been integrated to the upcoming VB.NET release, and this is the way it will work:

```
Public Const MyByte As Byte = 4UB;
Public Const MyByte2 As SByte = 4SB;
```

Answer (score 5):

This answer does not really provide a suffix, but it's as close as it gets.

If you define an extension method as

```
Imports System.Runtime.CompilerServices

Module IntegerExtensions

    <Extension()> _
    Public Function B(ByVal iNumber As Integer) As Byte
        Return Convert.ToByte(iNumber)
    End Function

End Module
```

You can use it like this:

```
Private Function GetTheAnswerAsByte() As Byte

   Return 42.B

End Function
```

Comment: +1. Although this probably won't work inside constants section.

Answer (score 3):

There's no byte literal in .NET.