# Ensure number is cast correctly in .NET

Tags: .net, casting, byte

I know that I can assign a value specifically to a float by doing

```
float y = 4.5f;
```

I want to do the same thing, except as a byte. How do I do this? I've checked the MSDN documentation and cannot find anything related to this. Also, what is this called?

Thanks,

**[Edit]**

For clarity the code I'm using this on is

```
byte myByte = a==b?1:0;
```

and the error I get is

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'int'
>   to 'byte?'. An explicit conversion
>   exists (are you missing a cast?)

Solution

```
byte myByte = (byte)(a==b?1:0);
```

Comment: I would call that a 'literal', not a cast--you're not casting anything

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `byte`, `sbyte`, `short` and `ushort` data types do not have designated suffixes. However, integer literal can be assigned to variables of these data types and will be implicitly converted, assuming that the value is appropriate for storage in the variable. Just for the record here are the defined literals in C#:

```
uint: U or u
long: L or l
ulong: UL or ul
float: F or f
decimal: M or m
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know the term suffix, had I known it Fredrik's link to the other SO post would have come up #1

Answer (score 2):

I would just use a cast.

```
// Okay
Byte data = (Byte) 57;

// Error (but I don't know if it is a compiler error or a runtime error)
Byte data = (Byte) -17;
```

Or introduce a constant.

```
// Okay
const Byte foo = 57;
Byte data = foo;

// Compiler Error
const Byte foo = -17;
Byte data = foo;
```

Comment: Not really necessary as long as the value is less than 256, unless you type 'var' to use type inference.

Comment: @Arjan, in my situation it's: byte myByte = a==b?1:0; and I need a cast.

Comment: I wouldn't use one here - but I could imagine situations where you could give hints to the compiler or run time that the result is wrong by an explicit cast. Very artificial example and not realy releated to the question. int foo = (Byte) Bar(); where Bar() returns an integer but you exspect the result to be in the byte range.

Comment: The conditional operator is a very good example - the compiler is not very good at infering the type.

Answer (score 2):

According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252817/vb-net-whats-the-suffix-type-character-for-byte-numeric-constants), byte has no such suffix.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a suffix when defining a byte:

```
   byte b = 1;
```

You just need to ensure that your value is between 0 and 255.

MSDN refers to the use of the F as a 'suffix', forcing a Literal Type.

See the following article at [C-sharp Online](http://en.csharp-online.net/CSharp_FAQ:_How_specify_a_CSharp_literal_type) for more information

Answer (score 1):

Hex notation:

Byte b = 0xff;

Comment: Could also be interpredet as a signed byte.

Comment: How different is 0xff from 255?

Comment: SByte foo = 0xFF; // Sets foo to -1.

Comment: Byte foo = 0xFF; // Sets foo to +255.