# Working with Byte literals

Tags: vb.net, byte, type-safety

I'm using the following function to brighten up color values (it's a lambda in my code, but that shouldn't make a differende):

```
Function ReduceDistanceTo255(ByVal i As Byte) As Byte
    Return i + (255 - i) \ 2
End Function
```

It won't compile, since the compiler interprets `255` and `2` as integers rather than bytes, making the result of type `Integer`. Unfortunately, [there is no Byte type character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252817), so I cannot just write `255B` or something like that.

There are a few obvious workarounds to the problem:

```
Function ReduceDistanceTo255(ByVal i As Byte) As Byte
    Return i + (CByte(255) - i) \ CByte(2)
End Function
```

and

```
Function ReduceDistanceTo255(ByVal i As Byte) As Byte
    Return CByte(i + (255 - i) \ 2)
End Function
```

and

```
Function ReduceDistanceTo255(ByVal i As Byte) As Byte
    Dim FF As Byte = 255
    Dim two As Byte = 2

    Return i + (FF - i) \ two
End Function
```

The first one is just plain ugly and hard to read, because *every* literal needs to be `CByte`d. The second one performs calculations in integers and then converts the result to Byte, which is OK, but not as elegant as a pure-Byte operation. The third workaround doesn't require `CByte`s, but it's drawbacks are obvious.

Did I miss some (elegant) fourth option which allows me to do Byte-only-math without cluttering my formula with CBools?

Comment: I'm not a VB guy, so I won't take a crack at it as an answer. But it sounds like you've got all your bases covered. The only thing you didn't mention is to have it all integer, and let the caller worry about the casting to byte.

Comment: I don't think there is a clearer way. I would use number two. It is only one cast so I don't see what the big deal is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is specifically mentioned in the Visual Basic Language Specification, chapter 2.4.2:

> **Annotation** 
>   *> There isn’t a type
>   character for Byte because the most
>   natural character would be B, which is
>   a legal character in a hexadecimal
>   literal.*

Well, that's true I guess.  "Octet" got voted down too, no doubt.  Use Return CByte(...), it is cheaper than ToByte().

Comment: Thanks for digging up the documentation; at least I know now *why* there is no Byte type character.

Answer (score 1):

How about using constants:

```
Function ReduceDistanceTo255(ByVal i As Byte) As Byte
  Const bFF As Byte = 255    
  Const b02 As Byte = 2
  Return i + (bFF - i) \ b02
End Function
```

no conversion, no casting, no extra variables

Answer (score 0):

How about the easy way:

```
Imports System.Convert

Function ReduceDistanceTo255(ByVal i As Byte) As Byte
    Return ToByte(i + (255 - i) \ 2)
End Function
```

**Edit:** I'd prefer this workaround because it would do less casting and it is pretty clear to me what's going on.

Comment: How is that different? Except "ToByte" rather than "CByte"?