# How to force a specific overload?

Tags: vb.net, overloading

I'm using binary writer and I want to write a 0 to the file, I'm doing:

_writer.Write(0)

But it's writing an integer to the file when I want it to do byte, what's the correct way without just declaring a byte variable as 0?

Comment: Have you tried casting? CByte(0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`_writer.Write(CByte(0))` should do the trick.

Comment: +1 Especially because there are [no byte literals](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1859681/working-with-byte-literals) in VB.